# Is there a special word from religious literature for "reward" (given by God)?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a word originating from religious literature or scriptures for a reward given by God to a man or woman for good deeds etc. The words that I come across seem to be neutral in the sense that they could equally apply to secular cases. Reward, repay, reap, etc. do not necessarily have a religious connotation.

Comment: I think "reward" is the usual term, or "reward from God" if you want to be precise. See e.g. [this list](https://dailyverses.net/reward/kjv).

Comment: In Judaism, there is a term "s'char" which almost always translates to "reward" in this context, but can also be used in contexts completely unrelated to rewards from God, such as to mean "wages"

Answer (score 2):

"Blessing" (or "blessed", depending on sentence structure) very often has religious tones.

Comment: Agreed. Some other examples: "benediction," "grace" (or "a stroke of grace"), "absolution," "gift from god"

Comment: As far as I know, Christians believe that their God does not issue earthly 'rewards' in return for good deeds, and that any blessings etc are given freely, out of kindness, mercy, and so on. The reward comes after you die, if you qualify. I don't know about other faiths, but I suspect that most would embody the idea that genuine good deeds are not done in the hope of rewards.

Comment: @Julien  In M-W I see the following examples of "benediction". (a) He dismissed the congregation with a benediction. (b) The priest offered a benediction for the missing children. As if the word is used for part of a ceremony more so than act of god toward his subjects. Do you have example sentences?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I'm not sure it is possible to make much of a statement about "Christians believe" beyond the broadest strokes!  Some certainly do believe that they will be rewarded in this world as well, cf. [Creflo Dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creflo_Dollar#Finances_and_prosperity_gospel_teachings).

Comment: @stangdon - a very nice chap, I see. Busted for choking his 15 year old daughter. I have been an atheist for a number of decades, but I do recall that Jesus said something about the eye of a needle.

Comment: @stangdon - Jesus also said 'by their fruits ye shall know them'.

Comment: A  benediction in the context of your examples is a blessing given 'on behalf of' God, effectively a request for Him to bless the congregation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the word "**blessing**". There are other uses of the word, but when spoken of as something received from God it is as you describe - a personal gift or some other indication from God that shows his approval. I say 'personal', because a blessing always denotes approval, and Christian scriptures teach that certain gifts, such as aspects of creation, are given to all irrespective of whether God approves of a person or not (Matthew 5:45), so such things may perhaps not be termed as 'blessings'.

For a Biblical example of a personal blessing, see *Job 42:12*:

> The Lord **blessed** the latter days of Job more than his beginning; and he had fourteen thousand sheep, six thousand camels, a thousand yoke of oxen, and a thousand donkeys.

For context, this is precisely double what *Job 1:3* details the man had at first. The message is that God gifted him double what he had before he underwent a trial and remained faithful to God.

There are of course many different denominations of Christianity (as well as the fact this example comes from the Jewish, Hebrew scriptures) that interpret and understand the Bible in different ways. Some teach that certain gifts from God are never taken away. Some term this 'grace'. But there are some biblical accounts that talk about God 'removing' his blessing such as at *1 Chronicles 28:9*, where it says "*if you leave him, he will reject you forever*".

Also, beyond Judeo-Christian texts, many other faiths including Hindi and Islam contain words for the same thing which are usually translated as 'blessing' in English.

Comment: I can say for sure in Judaism that "blessing" and "reward" are not synonymous at all. Sometimes blessing can be a reward (it doesn't always have to be), but other things can be a reward as well. There are different words and connotations for the two, and what OP is describing would almost always be translated as just "reward" (or even "payment") from Biblical Hebrew.

Comment: @Esther Would you agree that "**a** blessing" is different from simply being "blessed"? That's certainly how I understand it... that being blessed simply means having God's approval, but if a particular thing is described as a blessing then it is a gift, or at least an *indicator* of that approval.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'rewards' in this life, there is no such word in Christianity because it doesn't work like that!

> He makes the sun rise on the evil and on the good, and sends rain on the just and on the unjust. (Matthew 5:45)